# Formula to match column value with another column and add rows

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to match a value in one column to another, then add the two values which are in different rows. Given:

```
     A      B     C      D

1  Mustang  300  Camaro  70
2  Corvette 700  F150    82
3  Charger  218  Impala  74
4  Firebird 200  Mustang 66
```

There is a match, A1 = C4.  So, add values B1 and D4, in a new column E.

Here's what I've tried:

```
=(Index(A1:D4,Match(A1,C:C,0),D) + B1)
```

The match (if true) should return the row in C.  Then I tried INDEX to use the matched row with the column I want to add to B1.  I tried this for Row 1 and it returned nothing, which was correct.  When I dragged it down the column though, it did not work with any.

Comment: you were almost there! you've got some good info below, but just to tell you *why* your formula didn't work: 1) you need to lock the range `$A$1:$D$4`. 2) if the `Match` function does not find a result, it will return an error, so you would need to use an `IF(ISERROR` formula, like this: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),B1,INDEX($A$1:$D$4,MATCH(A1,C:C,0),4)+B1)`. The `SUMIF` solution below is simpler, but I thought I would show this to you so you can understand where you went wrong with **this** method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Also good to know about locking values, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=D1+SUMIF(A:A,C1,B:B)
```

`SUMIF` returns the total of column B for rows in column A that matches cell C1. It works if the values in column A are unique.

Comment: to keep it in line with the original formula, OP can also use `=B1+SUMIF(C:C,A1,D:D)`. Also, good job on finding a solution that does not requiring handling errors when values are not found :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to lock the range to save your range criteria with "$":

e.g.: =(Index($A$1:$D$4,Match(A1,C:C,0),D) + B1)

Maybe you are looking for VLOOKUP formula. It returns a value the you are looking for, #NA otherwise. Maybe something like (at E1 cell):

=VLOOKUP(C1,$B$1:$B$4,1,FALSE)

The fact is, neither VLOOKUP or MATCH can return both coordinates to you (line and row). You have to work based on column by column.

All the best

Comment: this will fail when the `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` do not find results.

Comment: That is why I mentioned about #NA. In this case, use ISNA function